# Expected value of a Binomial distribution where x~bin(25, 0.2)

Tags: binomial-distribution

This is an example from the text I'm using but I just want to make sure that I'm not going crazy here.

A multiple choice exam consists of 25 questions each with five choices with
once choice is correct. Randomly select an answer for each question. Let X
be the random variable representing the total number of correctly answered
questions.

(c) Find the expected value of the number of correct answers.

a and b are inconsequential, my issue is with (c).

The expected value is just $n*p$ is it not? The answer in the book says it is $(25)(0.2)(.8)$ but that makes absolutely no sense to me as that is the variance, not the expected value.

Comment: E(x) = n*p which for your example is 5

Comment: Alright, so then the text is wrong. This is what I thought, but I wasn't sure. Thank you!

Comment: you can also use sum of (r * p(x=r)) which ought to give the same thing as a double check

Comment: The answer book has given the Variance not the Mean